# Trying to get interval function to work with my factory

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I create a factory where I put my http request for adding, retrieving and deleting tasks.

Now when I add a task you don't see the visual change. I have to refresh the browser. Now to fix this I figured I would write a function to check the length of the old array against the length of the new one and set an interval off 1 minutes on it to make this change and then pull in the tasks. I am able to log my length change of the array but nothing happens visually (still have to refresh the browser).

If anybody could help me out here.

Part of my app.js code:

global vars -> defaultStart, defaultEnd, clickDate

```
zazzleApp.factory('TaskService', function ($http) {
    var TaskService = {};

    TaskService.taskList = [];

    TaskService.getTasks = function(cb){
        $http.get('api/task/all')
            .success(function(dataFromServer){

                for (var i = 0; i < dataFromServer.length; i++) {
                    TaskService.taskList[i] = dataFromServer[i];
                };

                //console.log('LOGGING GET_TASK ',  TaskService.taskList);
                if(cb){
                    cb(dataFromServer);
                }else{
                    return dataFromServer;
                }

                //return dataFromServer;

            })
            .error(function(errorFromServer){
            //something went wrong, process the error here
                console.log("Error in getting the users from the server ", errorFromServer);
            })
    };

    TaskService.addTask = function(pTask){
        var newClickDate = clickDate;
        console.log('LOGGGING NEW CLICK DATE = ', newClickDate);

        var newEditId = editId;
        //console.log('LOGGGING NEW edit id = ', newEditId);
        var url;

        if (newEditId) {
            url = 'api/task/update/' + newEditId;
        } else {
            url = 'api/task/create';
        }

        //console.log("URL URL USA", url, newEditId, newClickDate);

        defaultStart = new Date(newClickDate);
        defaultStart = defaultStart.getFullYear() + "-" + (defaultStart.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + defaultStart.getDate();
        defaultStart += " 00:00:00";

        defaultEnd = new Date(newClickDate).addDays(1);
        defaultEnd = defaultEnd.getFullYear() + "-" + (defaultEnd.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + defaultEnd.getDate();
        defaultEnd += " 00:00:00";

        console.log('LOGGING DEFAULT START AND DEFAULT END ' , defaultStart, defaultEnd);

        pTask.color = $('#containerColorPicker').attr('ng-data-id');

        // returns makes sure the promis is returned from the server
        return $http.post(url, {
            'name': pTask.project_name,
            'project_id': pTask.project_type,
            'location_id': pTask.location,
            'estimate_time': pTask.estimate_time || 2,
            'project_client_name': pTask.project_client_name,
            'url': pTask.url,
            'resource_link': pTask.resource_link,
            'notes': pTask.notes,
            'start_time': pTask.start_time || defaultStart,
            'end_time': pTask.end_time || defaultEnd,
            /*'start_time': defaultStart,
            'end_time': defaultEnd,*/
            'color': pTask.color
        }, {
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "text/plain"
            }
        })
        .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                console.log(data);
                TaskService.getTasks();
                TaskService.taskList.push(data);//pushing the new task
                //console.log("YYYYYYYYYYYYY -------->>>>>", defaultStart);
        })
        .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            console.log("Failed to add the task to DB");
        });
    };

    TaskService.deleteTask = function (){
        var newEditId= editId;
        $http.delete('api/task/delete/' + newEditId)
            .success(function(dataFromServer){

                console.log('logging edit id in delete taks func server ', newEditId);

                var index;

                for (var i = 0; i < TaskService.taskList.length; i++) {
                    if(TaskService.taskList[i]._id == newEditId){
                        //index = i;
                        console.log ("removing the element from the array, index: ", newEditId, i);
                        TaskService.taskList.splice(i,1);
                    }
                };
                /*  if(editId !== -1){
                    console.log ("removing the element from the array, index: ", editId, index);
                    UserService.userList.splice(index,1);
                }*/

                console.log('TaskArray ', TaskService.taskList)
                $('div[ng-data-id="'+ newEditId +'"]').remove();

            })
            .error(function(errorFromServer){
                //something went wrong, process the error here
                console.log("Error in deleting a user from the server");
            })
    };

    return TaskService;
})


//START CONTROLLER
angular.module('zazzleToolPlannerApp')
    .controller('CalendarCtrl', function ($scope, $mdDialog, $http, $rootScope, $timeout, User, Auth, UserService, TaskService) {

    $scope.newTask = {};
    $scope.newTask.project_name = "";
    $scope.newTask.project_type = "";
    $scope.newTask.location = "";
    $scope.newTask.estimate_time = "";
    $scope.newTask.project_client_name = "";
    $scope.newTask.url = "";
    $scope.newTask.resource_link = "";
    $scope.newTask.notes = "";
    $scope.newTask.color = "";

    $scope.tasks = TaskService.taskList;

    $scope.getTasksFromService = function () {
        TaskService.getTasks(); //after this gets called, the data will be shown in the page automatically
    }
    $scope.getTasksFromService();

    $scope.addTaskWithService = function () {
        //note that you can process the promise right here (because of the return $http in the service)
        TaskService.addTask($scope.newTask)
            .success(function(data){
                //here you can process the data or format it or do whatever you want with it
                console.log("Controller: the task has been added");
                $scope.tasks = [];// EMPTY THE ARRAY
                $scope.tasks = TaskService.getTasks();
                //console.log('Taskservice Controller ', $scope.updateGridDataAwesome);
            })
            .error(function(data){
                //something went wrong
                console.log("Controller: error in adding task");
            });
    }

    $scope.deleteTaskWithService = function(){
        TaskService.deleteTask();
    }

TaskService.getTasks(function(data){
    $scope.tasks = data;
});

var interval = setInterval(function(){
    var oldLength = $scope.tasks.length;
    TaskService.getTasks(function(data){
        console.log('lengths', oldLength, data.length)
        if(oldLength != data.length){
            //$scope.tasks = data; 
            //TaskService.taskList.push(data);
            $scope.tasks = TaskService.getTasks();

        }
    });
}, 6000)
```

Comment: So when u call service u call get method and u put your tasks in array of objects ok? On add u send post request on server. so when u refresh u call again get method and u fetch that newly created object. If u want to see it without refresh just push that newly created object in array of objects. $scope.tasks.push(newTask). You can do that in button submit function

Answer (score 0):

This might be what you're looking for, by using `$interval` you can set an interval every x seconds:

```
$interval(function() {
  // Something to be executed after 1min (60000ms)
}, 60000);
```

And then inject `$interval` into your factory:

```
zazzleApp.factory('TaskService', function ($http, $interval).....
```

Comment: @GY22 Could you shorten your code to only include where the problem is?

Comment: the code i gave above is the essential part. I believe you just have to focus on the addTask

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$http
    .post("/api/pin", {})
    .success(function(data) {
        $scope.$apply(function() {
            $scope.pins.push(data);
        });
    });
```

reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24836089/3330947

Update:

I did it like this:

Service (fetch all accounts):

```
.factory('accountService', function ($http) {
        var accountObj = {
            async: function () {
                var promise = $http.get('account/').then(function (response) {
                    return response;
                });
                return promise;
            }
        };
        return accountObj;
    })
```

Controller:

```
//Call get accounts service and put all accounts in $scope.accounts
    var getAccounts = function () {
        accountService.async().then(function (d) {
            $scope.accounts = d.data;}
    }
//Create new account and update array of accounts
    $scope.createAccount = function () {
        $scope.data = {
                'id' : 0,
                'customerId' : $scope.outputCustomer[0].id,
                'camsId' : $scope.outputCams[0].id,
                'camsPin' : parseInt($scope.camsPin),
                'username' : $scope.username,
                'password' : $scope.password,
                'email' : $scope.email,
                'acfUsername' : $scope.acfUsername,
                'accountActive' : $scope.accountActive,
                'agentId' : $scope.outputAgent[0].id,
                'freeswitchIds' : freeswitchIds
        };
        $http.post('account/save', $scope.data).success(
                function (data, status) {
                    $scope.accounts.push(data);
                }).error(function () {
                });
        };
```

My add function is in controller, i thin it can be redone to be service but this work soo

Comment: @dev_in_progess. if i apply $scope.$apply(function() {
            $scope.pins.push(data);
        }); in my succes . i get an error -> https://gyazo.com/e86ed78625dc5e4467f5df29b99a2709

Comment: whel u dont have $scope defined, add $scope in your factory

Comment: -> mmm this does not seem to help (https://gyazo.com/c4c40dbb258dab5ac5798e8fbf68d67c)

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be in `success` of `addTask`. `TaskService.getTask`is async. So the execute order will be: 1. http request in `TaskService.getTasks` 2. TaskService.taskList.push(data); 3. `$http` success callback.

```
.success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        console.log(data);
        TaskService.getTasks();
        TaskService.taskList.push(data);//pushing the new task
        //console.log("YYYYYYYYYYYYY -------->>>>>", defaultStart);
})
```

In this order, step 2 is pointless. Because step 3 code may override `TaskService.taskList`

```
for (var i = 0; i < dataFromServer.length; i++) {
    TaskService.taskList[i] = dataFromServer[i];
};
```

And another wrong place:

```
$scope.tasks = TaskService.getTasks();
```

this line code appears twice. But `TaskService.getTasks()` returns `undefined` because you don't put keyword `return`.

In addition, your practice to use `promise` is wrong. `$http` leverages `promise` specification.  Don't use callback since  you used `promise`.  You may need read `promise` docs.